Angular set filename in input file element programmatically
I have angular app with one modal dialog which has input file field and "Next" and "Back" buttons.
If I select a file and go to the next view and then going back to upload file dialog I would like to show previously selected file in input field.
Currently I'm getting this error :
ERROR DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': 
This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.

ois it possible to do somehow ?
<ds-modal>

  <ds-box-content>
        <ds-form-field>
          <label ds-label for="file">Excel-File</label>
          <input ds-input
                 #fileInput
                 id="file"
                 type="file"
                 formControlName="file"
                 [accept]="acceptFileType"
                 [labellingConfig]="labellingConfig"
                 (change)="extractUploadedFile($event)"
                 required
          />
        </ds-form-field>
  </ds-box-content>
  
    <button
      ds-button
      *ngIf="showBackButton$ | async"
      [variant]="'outline'"
      class="modal-button"
      (click)="onBackClick()"
    >
      Back
    </button>
</ds-modal>

export class MyComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('fileInput') fileInputRef!: ElementRef;

  maxSize = 10;
  acceptFileType: string = '.xlsx';
  labellingConfig: DsInputLabellingConfig = {
    empty: 'No File selected',
    addFilesSingle: 'Add file',
    fileCounter: '',
    addFilesMultiple: ''
  };

  selectedFileType: string = FileTypeEnum.EXCEL;

  reactiveForm = new FormGroup({
    file: new FormControl('', {
      validators: [Validators.required],
    })
  });


  uploadedXlsxFile?: File;

  onBackClick() {
    this.selectedFileType = this.savedFileType ?? FileTypeEnum.EXCEL;
    this.uploadedXlsxFile = this.savedUploadedXlsxFile;
    if (this.uploadedXlsxFile) {
      this.reactiveForm.controls['file'].setValue(this.uploadedXlsxFile.name);
    } else {
      this.reactiveForm.controls['file'].reset();
    }

  }

  }


The error is complaining about your
this.reactiveForm.controls['file'].setValue(this.uploadedXlsxFile.name);

line, because you attempt to set the value of the file, but it has no value, but it has a filename instead. But, as the error tells you, you cannot set it programmatically to anything else than an empty string.
Therefore, you may consider simply uploading the file, mimicking the input in subsequent views and depending on the result of user actions either removing/forgetting the file if the flow did not end properly, or storing the content thusly received long-term.
